# Attempting to retag a question redirects me to another question

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, tags

As per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57192/merge-newbies-newbie-into-new-users) question, I went through and started retagging the questions with the "newbie" tag (the one that had fewer) to "new users".

But when I try to click the tags box of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/can-and-should-more-be-done-to-encourage-users-to-search-first-and-ask-only-if) question, I am redirected to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/please-charge-rep-for-questions-after-threshold) question.  I've managed to retag the other ones in the "newbie" tag okay, it's just *that* one.  (If it's significant: Firefox 3.6.6 on Windows XP.)

Is this a bug, or some functionality I'm not aware of?  This is my first real attempt at retagging other people's questions.

Comment: There's definitely something wrong with that question, the links inside the question look ok, but it doesn't work.  Looks like either a length problem, or a list problem or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question had old/bad markup which needed to be re-saved. I added a space, clicked save. Done..

Answer (score 0):

The tag field overlaps with that [related] link. Reproduced with FF3.6.6.win