# Make the how-to-ask site agnostic

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

Regarding this [from the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/):

> Furthermore, this page is designed to be shared and reusable. Free to share the How to Ask link with any question asker in need of advice on how to improve their question.

I assume this can be deployed to every site fairly easily, so that would be my first choice, but if that's not possible for some reason, could you add the option to hide the *proceed* link based on some parameter?
That would be useful to link to it from another SE site, not confusing the user when he clicks proceed and he's redirected to SO's ask-a-question-page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/can-and-should-more-be-done-to-encourage-users-to-search-first-and-ask-only-if/9710#9710) indicates that this is deployed to all sites but disabled. Only SO has it switched on for the time being.

> edit: this is now deployed, and enabled on Stack Overflow only.

The position of comma in that sentence makes a huge difference to how it could be interpreted, but as you discovered from your own tests, every SE site has an ask-advice page:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: Note: There's a `/help/how-to-ask` page that's (mostly?) identical network-wide, in addition to the `/questions/ask/advice` page that's customized on a few sites.

Comment: (To clarify: There's one site setting enabled on a small number of sites that causes users without the "remove new user restrictions" page to be redirected from the Ask Question page to the `/questions/ask/advice`. In addition, a separate setting lets us customize the intro section of the `/questions/ask/advice` page, which we've done for *some* of those sites.)

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this "How to Ask" page to be a feature of the SE platform and to reside in all sites, not just SO, as all the sites will face the same problem, at least after a while. Even when a site is picking up speed and new users join early on, it can be useful from the beginning, let's say when coming out of beta.

This said, I would then link the site specific page to a comment as proposed in the blog portion you quoted.