# All ask-advice pages refer to Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, user-interface, asking-questions

**EDIT:**  This has now been fixed. Any mod wants to add the status-completioned tag, feel free.

> Welcome to **Gaming**!
>
> We'd love to help you. But not every question on **Stack Overflow** gets answered. To improve your chances, here are some tips:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask-advice

> Welcome to **Super User**!
>
> We'd love to help you. But not every question on **Stack Overflow** gets answered. To improve your chances, here are some tips:

https://superuser.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed a while ago. This page is now referenced a few more places on all sites:

- in the /ask sidebar help when the body is focused
- in the /faq on all sites under /faq#deletion

... it is a forced interstitial for new users only on Stack Overflow, however.

Answer (score 6):

I see no error. No matter what site you are looking at, it is factually true that no every question on Stack Overflow gets answered.

Comment: Darn it! I forgot to make that joke in the question.  Can I start over?

Answer (score 2):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

> **For now, these measures are (mostly) only enabled on Stack Overflow**, as it’s the only site large enough to have these big city problems at the moment. But we certainly hope all of our Stack Exchange network sites get large enough to run into this .. what’s the cliche, again? “nice problem to have?”

Until it is announced that all SE 2.0 sites get the page also, this is not yet a problem.

Comment: yes I saw this, but the page has been deployed *to all sites*.  Forcing a <10 user to read it is only enabled on SO. As the blog post explains, the page is designed to stand on its own so that it can be shared, for example, when asking a user to improve their post.  See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66560/make-the-how-to-ask-site-agnostic.