# “Karma” Or “SO”?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does it feel lately like all questions have already been asked and answered and there is nothing more to do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87743/does-it-feel-lately-like-all-questions-have-already-been-asked-and-answered-and-t)

I have read the article of http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/   and delighted.Many new things I have learnt from this article I am really thankful of  **Jeff Atwood** and **Robert Harvey.**

**If people believe in them self than nothing is impossible for them.** This is the great thing I have learnt from this article and I like to draw the attention of our community towards the  heading of the above article is **If you are a help Vampires**  in which the author greatly described the way and meaning of “Karma”.

Now  suppose if people try to solve their question’s answer by searching through **Google,MSDN Articles, News Magazine,  By Online Books, By Purchasing Books, and By other Communities**

than I think there are no question remain to ask over “SO”

So what next?. **To believe in Self “Karma” Or “SO”.**

The simple question is that if people have a question and they try to solve their own as suggested above way as per above article and they have solved it their own than is it possible to ask the same thing  here at “SO”?.

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand what your question is.

Comment: I did not understand you point / question / discussion topic?

Comment: What was that again?

Comment: Woah. You just made my Monday surreal.

Comment: @YOU, Sorry It is not exactly duplicates.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, what you didn't get the words "Karma"?. If So then Please Read the above articles.

Comment: @mahesh: I've attempted to make sense of your question. Please read and indicate if it reflects your intentions...

Comment: @Shog Well played.

Comment: So enthused, so crushed, so meta.

Comment: @Shog9, Sorry it's changed the entire intention. If you try hard to solve the question's answer by other way as suggested above than there is nothing remain to ask at "SO"

Comment: .... I am specifically concern with older software question like VS-2005, not new

Comment: @mahesh: in that case, it's a duplicate of the question linked to above. I've rolled back and closed as indicated.

Comment: ... actually last three lines changed the entire meaning of question.

Comment: @mahesh: FWIW, you may also be interested in this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3734/how-long-should-i-search-for-an-answer-before-i-ask-on-stackoverflow-and-friends

Comment: @Shog9, Ok than there is nothing remain to discuss as it is closed as duplicated but my freind it is not exact duplicate or duplicate.

Comment: ... there is no single point in my question which is match to your suggested link.

Comment: @mahesh: Your question, as written, is *extremely* unclear. The best interpretation of myself and other readers, taking your comments into account, puts it as an effective duplicate of the question now linked at the top. If you do not feel this is appropriate, you *must* strive to clarify what you are truly asking, and how it differs significantly from what is being answered in that existing question. I appreciate that you may be struggling to communicate using English and that this may be compounding your difficulties in resolving this, but can only encourage you to continue your studies.

Comment: *If people believe in them self than nothing is impossible for them. This is the great thing I have learnt from this article* – but did you also learn what the article is about? And: do you think you're a help vampire?

Comment: @Arjan, Sorry but you are not get my question well because there is asking different and you are replying different.

Comment: ... I am point out to particular a one head of a article and you targeting different thing.

Comment: So you're asking why are you are suspended for asking questions which are hard to understand or interpret over and over again?

Comment: Ah, shucks... No _real_ vampires? Not interested.

Comment: @MrDisappointment - I just like your name in this context :-)

Comment: *particular a one head of a article* — well, mahesh, @Shog9 clarified what section you were referring to but then you didn't like that edit either, leaving us with something we don't understand. Surely *we* are to blame for that, but just a little mind game: what if *you* were the help vampire after all? Then how would you say we should react to your questions?

Comment: @Arjan, Sorry this question is not for you, it is simple question, it is for those who try to understand. it is not for those who know it but pretend to not understand it. thanks....

Comment: @random, I accepted my suspension very greatly, but there is certain points in my mind to start new session after completed suspension period, which would help me to continue with this community. it's the only concern efforts for that. I hope this answer fulfilled your requirement.

Comment: @mahesh so now you're declaring this your *personal* help site? Help Vampire at its best, I'd say. Success!

Comment: @Arjan, Good question Arjan, I am appreciate to reply it. If it is my personal sites than it will be open for all including Vampire and remeber this is knowledge base side here vampire also having good knowledge. and they have not drink the blood but also spread the knowledge. that is importance of educational site. remeber this for only if it is my personal site.

Comment: ... and who spread the knowledge is not vampire but they are angel and keep in mind that works of spread knowledge is of angel duty.

Answer (score 3):

Mahesh - I think your assumption that "there are no question remain to ask over “SO” (sic)" is flawed. There will always be more questions unanswered in the world than answered, so while it is definitely a good idea to google first (and one would hope google would point to SO or the rest of the SE family if an answer exists) and if nothing is found then feel free to ask.

There is an amazingly enthusiastic bunch of skilled and experienced individuals here, it just saves a lot of time and effort for a questioner to check for answers first - both on google, and on the stack exchange search engine.

Comment: +1 I was typing up a guess as to what I thought would answer this and this pretty much sums up what I was going to say.

Comment: @Rory Alsop, OK than you believe in that if world has no answer than SO has answer, That means SO Solved the all unanswer question, there are no unanswer question pending.

Comment: And don't forget that the IT field is ever changing! There are LOADS more problems we haven't run into yet! I, for one, am super excited!

Comment: @mahesh - no. I believe that if the world has no answer available, SO might, as SO is a subset of world that you can ask.

Comment: @John, I agree with you but i am talking about older version software question like VS-2005. It still has been asking over there.

Comment: @mahesh - over where? Now you're losing me again....

Comment: @Rory Alsop, I mean at "SO"